# Warn if outgoing Outlook message contains certain number patterns, i.e. SSN, credit card numbers

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I have found multiple variations of this question but none that actually work for me.

What I need to do is check outgoing message in Outlook, before sending, to make sure there are no **`SSN's`**, credit card numbers, etc.  It also needs to check different type patterns.

For example, someone may put `SSN as 123-45-6789` or `123456789`.
I have tried one solution that used an Excel file to list private information, modifying one that checked for a certain word in the subject line, etc.

The problem I have is searching the body & searching patterns instead of specific text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use proper formatting.

Comment: I apologize.  I am looking for where I messed up on the formatting but I don't see it.  Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Maybe you can add some more space on between paragraphs.. you can also remove `thank you` as this is considered noise.

Comment: Sorry, not worth responding to that except to say that I will try to do better next time.  And, "thank you", in my opinion, is never noise.

Comment: I understand your opinion on the wording "thank you". I often consider them required. But according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), there is no need to say `Thank you` in answers, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I am simply repeating this for each pattern of numbers I am looking for.  Is there a way to make a list of the different patterns & then check each item in the list?

```
    Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

      Dim myMailToSend As MailItem
      Dim re As Object
      Dim s As String
    '****************************
      Const sPat As String = "\b\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\b"
    Set myMailToSend = Item
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        re.Pattern = sPat

    s = myMailToSend.Body & " " & myMailToSend.Subject

    If re.Test(s) = True Then

            strMsg = "The current item contains sensitive information. Do you still want to send it?"
              nResponse = MsgBox(strMsg, vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Check Sensitive Information")
              If nResponse = vbYes Then
                   Cancel = False
                Else
                   Cancel = True
              End If
    Else

    End If
'****************************
  Const tPat As String = "\b\d{2}-\d{7}\b"
Set myMailToSend = Item
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Pattern = tPat

s = myMailToSend.Body & " " & myMailToSend.Subject

If re.Test(s) = True Then

        strMsg = "The current item contains sensitive information. Do you still want to send it?"
          nResponse = MsgBox(strMsg, vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Check Sensitive Information")
          If nResponse = vbYes Then
               Cancel = False
            Else
               Cancel = True
          End If
Else

End If
```

Comment: You could load the patterns into an array and then use a `For Each` around the search and replace code. `Dim Patterns() As Variant` `Dim PatternCrnt As Variant` `Patterns = Array("\b\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\b"
, "\b\d{2}-\d{7}\b", ...)` `For Each PatternCrnt in Pattern` search and replace code `Next`

Comment: I'll try that.  Thank you Tony, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @TonyDallimore you can simply use Use "|" OR, see my answer

Comment: Tony & 0m3r were right on target.  Thank you both for taking the time to help me.  I sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use **"`|`"** OR  operator

*Example `/(a|b)/` Matches the **`a`** or the **`b`** part*

*So your Pattern  should be **`"\b\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\b|\b\d{2}-\d{7}\b|\b\d{9}\b"`***

---

*Demo -* *https://regex101.com/r/a1QaZb/1*

> [image]

[image]

*And your code should look like the following-*

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim myMailToSend As mailitem
    Dim re As Object
    Dim s As String
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim nResponse As String
    '****************************
    Const sPat As String = "\b\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\b|\b\d{2}-\d{7}\b|\b\d{9}\b"

    Set myMailToSend = Item
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Pattern = sPat

    s = myMailToSend.Body & " " & myMailToSend.subject

    If re.test(s) = True Then
        strMsg = "The current item contains sensitive information." & _
                                    "Do you still want to send it?"

        nResponse = MsgBox(strMsg, vbExclamation + vbYesNo, _
                                    "Check Sensitive Information")
        If nResponse = vbYes Then
            Cancel = False
        Else
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  This is definitely better than my way.